# How do I get the DateTime that a page was last published in Sitefinity?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, telerik, sitefinity

Here is what I have:

```
Dim cmsManager As New Telerik.Cms.CmsManager()
Dim currentNode As Telerik.Cms.Web.CmsSiteMapNode = CType(SiteMap.CurrentNode, Telerik.Cms.Web.CmsSiteMapNode)
Dim currentPage As Telerik.Cms.ICmsPage = currentNode.GetCmsPage()
Dim currentPageId As Guid = currentPage.ID
Dim pageFromDb As Telerik.Cms.IPage = cmsManager.GetPage(currentPageId)

Me.LastUpdateDate = pageFromDb.DateModified
```

Unfortunately `.DateModified` returns the last time that a page was edited instead of when it was last published. I've been looking through [the documentation](http://www.sitefinity.com/help/developer-manual/pages-interfaces.html) but I haven't been able to find any corresponding properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code I'm using now, it seems to be getting the correct date on Publish:

```
Dim cmsManager As New Telerik.Cms.CmsManager()
Dim currentPageId As New Guid(SiteMap.CurrentNode.Key)
Dim pageFromDb As Telerik.Cms.IPage = cmsManager.GetPage(currentPageId, False)
Dim staged As Telerik.Cms.IStagedPage = pageFromDb.GetVersion(pageFromDb.Version)

Me.LastUpdateDate = staged.DateModified
```

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do it though.

Answer (score 1):

For version 10, I'm using the following code:

```
var node = SiteMapBase.GetActualCurrentNode();
var itemVersions = VersionManager.GetManager().GetItemVersionHistory(node.PageId);
var lastPublishedItem = itemVersions.Where(i => i.IsLastPublishedVersion).FirstOrDefault();
var lastPublishedDate = lastPublishedItem.LastModified.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy");
```

I wish there's a more straight forward way to do this..